# Using cal command of Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, calendar, unix

When I want to see a calendar on Ubuntu, I just command like this:

```
$ cal -3
```

Then, it displays prev/current/next month output.

But, the `cal` command of OSX is a bit different from Ubuntu's, and there's no `-3` option.

If I see the history section of man page, OSX's looks like this

> A cal command appeared in Version 5 AT&T UNIX. The ncal command appeared in FreeBSD 2.2.6.

And, the history section of [Ubuntu's man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/cal.1.html) says

> A cal command appeared in Version 6 AT&T UNIX. Several much more elaborate versions of this program exist, with support for colors, holidays, birthdays, reminders and appointments, etc. For example, try the cal from http://home.sprynet.com/~cbagwell/projects.html or GNU gcal.

Can I use Ubuntu's `cal` command on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been searching for `cal -3` functionality on Mac as well.

From your quote, there's an alternative, [GNU gcal](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/), which is radically different from cal command. There's a [tutorial](http://www.mostlymaths.net/2010/04/gcal-ultra-powerful-command-line-gnu.html) that's easy to follow as well.

So I settled with it. You can type `gcal .` for `cal -3` equivalent.

Comment: Do you know why it shows calendar in a vertical format on some machine?

Comment: I believe it's the locale stuff. `LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 gcal` gave me a vertical format.

Comment: Yes, it was locale problem. Thank you! I don't know why the `gcal` show a vertical format in Korean locale. We don't use the vertical format. :(